# Different meanings of の？

Tags: grammar, particle-の

> もう１つの大{おお}きな政党{せいとう}の共和党{きょうわとう}からはドナルド・トランプさんが出{で}ました

This seems simple enough but I don't know how to properly translate. Literally:

> About from the Republican party of the large political party of another one, Donald Trump (appeared?).

"The Republican party *of the* political party" is probably not what the の means here, but I'm not familiar with other meanings of の.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The の is an appositive (同格) particle.

> もう１つの大きな政党**の**共和党からは...

You could rephrase it as もう１つの大きな政党**である**共和党からは...

"From the other major political party, (that is,) the Republican Party, ..."
"From the Republican Party, (which is) the other major political party, ..."

Examples:

- 友達**の**山田くん (my friend Yamada-kun)
- のねずみ**の**ぐりとぐら (field mice Guri and Gura)
- 被害者**の**男性 (a man who is a victim; a male victim)

---

> ドナルド・トランプさんが出ました
>   Donald Trump (appeared?)

The 出る means [立候補]{りっこうほ}する or [出馬]{しゅつば}する, "to run (as a candidate / for president)".